# Select Records From MySql on PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with records like this

```
country_name   username
------------------------
India          abc1
Australia      abc2
India          abc3
USA            abc4
Australis      abc5
Lebanon        abc6
```

From Above Table I need to get country list without repeat, is there any chance to get like this...

Ex Code:

```
$sql = 'bla bla bla bla bla';
$res = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    echo $row['country_name'].'<br /><br />';
}
```

Ex Output(Like this):

```
India
Australia
USA
Lebanon
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT country_name FROM table
```

Comment: Please, tell me how it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

The group by method is better if you want to select more than just the country name with your query...like:
$sql = "SELECT country_name, username FROM table GROUP BY country_name;

but if you just want to select country name, DISTINCT is slightly faster.

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT country_name FROM table";